# @IBSegueAction with condition

Tags: swift, swiftui, ibsegueaction

In my app I want to perform a segue based on a UITapGestureRecognizer. In case the tap is in the top area of the screen, a segue to the SettingsView should be performed.

In UIKit this was quite simple. I've triggered the performSegue in the UITapGestureRecognizer by wrapping it in an if-statement.

Now I would like to write the SettingsView() in SwiftUI. The SettingsView() will be embedded in a UIHostingController.

My question is:
How can I perform the segue to this UIHostingController (while telling the UIHostingController which View to display)?

I tried to use the new @IBSegueAction. The reason to use this @IBSegueAction is that I can use it to tell the UIHostingController which View to display. The problem is that I can't insert a condition now. Wherever the tap is on the screen, the segue is performed. I haven't found a way to cancel the segue in @IBSegueAction.

My code currently looks like this:

```swift
    @IBSegueAction func showSettingsHostingControler(_ coder: NSCoder, sender: UITapGestureRecognizer, segueIdentifier: String?) -> UIViewController? {

        let location = sender.location(in: self.tableView)
        if let _ = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: location) {
            return nil
        } else {
            if location.y < 32 {
                if location.x < view.bounds.midX {
                    direction = .left
                } else {
                    direction = .right
                }
                return UIHostingController(coder: coder, rootView: SettingsView())
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
```

The result currently is that the app segues to a non-existing Nil-view when the tap is in the wrong area.

Comment: The alternative would be to prepare the UIHostingController programmatically. But I didn't succeed this way neither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> based on a UITapGestureRecognizer. In case the tap is in the top area of the screen

It sounds to me like your tap gesture recognizer is attached to the wrong view. There should not be any decision to make here. Position a view in the top area of the screen and attach the tap gesture recognizer to that. That way, if this view gets a tap, there is no decision to be made: the tap is in the right place.

Comment: It‘s attached to a UITableView. But I only want to treat a tap on the table header like this

Comment: Then the tap gesture recognizer should be attached to the table header, as I just said.

Comment: I've now found a way to solve it programmatically:  `              let viewController = UIHostingController(rootView: SettingsView())
                self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
`

Comment: But that's just an ordinary presentation. You asked how to do it from inside a `IBSegueAction`. So that is what I responded to.

Comment: Yes, that‘s correct. Ideally I would have liked to perform such a segue programatically. My intermediate solution somehow does the job, but it‘s not what I was hoping for.

Comment: Well try my answer. It tells you how to trigger the segue only when the tap is in the right place.